# w3wp.exe exceeding max threads

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, threadpool, application-pool

we have requirement to handle 10000 concurrent user.

Let me explain the system. Machine has two processors. ProcessModel in machine.config is set as autoconfig = true. so that makes maxWorkerThreads = 20.

When I Load run my case with **30 users** and watch CPU usage it is maximing to 100. and number of threads on w3wp.exe is more then 70. As my default is 20 * 2 (CPU's) = 40.

Once cpu touches 100% most of the transaction fail or talking maximum time to respond

Now questions
1. how do i get 30 more threads assigned to the same workerprocess?
2. How can reduce CPU usage here?

Comment: If you truly have a requirement to handle 10,000 concurrent users, while this may be possible with specialized software and libraries - you'd be best advised to setup multiple servers and load-balance them.

Comment: I have a load balanced env. Firstly i am trying with 30 users in my case here. IIS is maximing only for 30 concurrent users.

Comment: What exactly is the question, 20 worker threads in the thread pool per processor doesn't necessarily mean that the w3wp.exe process is only going to use 40 threads.  Increasing the number of threads won't increase HTTP requests served if the CPU is maxed already.  Reducing CPU usage will require an analysis of the code.

Comment: Ken: I agree with you. Why do I have more then 40 threads?

Answer (score 1):

You have a bit of an issue here.  Increasing the # of threads will **further increase** CPU usage.  (Your 2 goals are incompatible.)  Not only are you asking each CPU to do more, but you'll have additional overhead with context switching.

You could investigate using a non-blocking IO library, which would essentially mean only 1-2 threads per CPU.  However, this could be a significant architecture change to your project (probably not feasible) - and what you might actually find is that most of the CPU was actually spent due to the work your code is performing, and not because of anything threading-related.

It sounds like you need to do some performance tuning and optimization of your application.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at making async calls so that your threads are not remaining active while the caller is waiting for a response.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163463.aspx